# How to Show double quotation with HTML code as text in Android (TextView) ?

Tags: android, html, android-layout, android-studio

I want to Show HTML code as Text in Tutorial App

**String.xml**

```
<string name="p1"><![CDATA[<html>\n<title> Font tag Example </title>\n<body>\n<font face="arial" size="1" color="blue"> WELCOME </font> <br>\n <font size="2" color="cyan"> WELCOME </font> <br>\n <pre>\n This text uses pre tag and preserves nextline and spaces\n </pre>\n </body>\n </html>]]></string>
```

**prog1.xml**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/p1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:text="@string/p1" />
```

**Show but without " ",   Need Show with " " double quotation**

[image: Display without double quotation]

**require Show  like this**

Answer (score 4):

to show double quote("") inside a textview use any of these

- `&quot;`
- \"

here is the official android website
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource

Answer (score 0):

Try it in your `string.xml`    `<string name="ffdfb">\"ffdfb\"</string>`
or
 `<string name="ffdfb">&quot;ffdfb&quot;</string>`

else try it in your xml `android:text='"fvdfv"'`